# PHP get contents of a div, and echo the div contents in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello and thank you for your help.
I'd like to do something similar for my website.

Simply that the loading of the page,
In php, I would like to take the content of a DIV.

And then display it anywhere on the page.

**Store in variable $texte1** all the contents of **the div id texte-1**

```
<?php $texte1 = get_contents_div('text-1'); ?>
```

**And put the content of the div in page**

```
<?php echo ($texte1);?>
```

Tank you for help friends
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: you can do this using javascript.....

Comment: jQuery `.html()` would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the php DomDocument class. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divContent = $xpath->query('//div[id="product_list"]');
```

Comment: no working !!The page stop load when i add your code !

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it in javascript:

```
<script>
(function(){
     var divContent= document.getElementById("text-1").html(); //get div content

     document.getElementsByTagName("body").append(divContent); //add it to the body
})();
</script>
```

Comment: i dont love javascript , because a lot of people use blocker !